# SSO in Xamarin Forms UWP app on Windows 10

Tags: windows, xamarin.forms, uwp, single-sign-on, access-token

We are working on a Xamarin Forms UWP app which has a requirement, when we click on the app icon,  automatically log into the app without having to enter any user details. The app should use the same credentials used to login to the Windows 10 device. Basically, sign in user without prompting them to login again, fetch access token and get data from API.

The user would use their enterprise credentials to login and are on the enterprise network

Can someone point me to the right direction on how can we achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what authentication mechanism does the API use?

Comment: Hi @Jason, it uses OAUTH2

Comment: Do you have any updates for this thread?

Comment: @Nico Zhu - MSFT, sorry for late response,  I am using Xamarin Essentials Web Authenticator already in the app, which opens a web browser popup,  the user is able to enter their credentials and retrieve token this way 
But for my case, the app should pick the user credentials who are signed into the operating system automatically without presenting the browser popup. I was referring to this link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-uwp-considerations. It talks about SSO by setting UseCorporateNetwork property to true. I tried many things but still stuck

Comment: Hi @KrishnaShinde have you got any work around for this? or any solution?

Answer (score 0):

> SSO in Xamarin Forms UWP app on Windows 10

You could use [**Xamarin.Essentials: Web Authenticator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android) to auth the specific and get token the store the data in to [`Application.Current.Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#Properties_Dictionary) like the following

```
Application.Current.Properties ["token"] = token;
```

When you open the app, you need check if `Application.Current.Properties ["token"]` contain the value, if the value is not null, you could login the app directly, if not, please get token and store it.

And if the token contains expiration time, you still need to check the if token is out of data and re-auth.